# UPDATE QUERY INSIDE WHILE LOOP: Adding Weight to Virtual Herd of Bisi

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

REVISED CODE: CLOSER TO DESIRED RESULT:

I modified the code so that each calf is assigned a random weight gain based on season of the year, as illustrated by the new code below.

However I am still not having any luck updating the table for each row. As soon as I remove the // mark from the sql Update statement, the page errors out.

UPDATE 28 APRIL:  Came across examples where the UPDATE function is the outside loop and the SELECT function is the inside loop, opposite to my code. Have tried various permutations of both approaches without any success.

CALF CODE:A20210416F0026 WEIGHT: 37.8

---

CALF CODE:A20210417F0027 WEIGHT: 44.9

---

CALF CODE:A20210418M0028 WEIGHT: 58.7

---

CALF CODE:A20210421F0029 WEIGHT: 60.5

---

CALF CODE:A20210422F0030 WEIGHT: 43.9

---

CALF CODE:A20210427M0032 WEIGHT: 57.9

---

```
<?PHP
$month = date('m');
```

$Dlbs = 0 ;

?>

```
<?PHP

$sql = "SELECT Acode,weight FROM herd WHERE age < 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    
    // POUNDS OF CALF WEIGHT DURING PRE-WEANING PERIOD
    
    if ($month > 3 && $month <=11) {
        
        $Slbs = rand(15,19) / 10 ;
        $Dlbs = $Slbs ;
    
    } else {
    
        $Wlbs = rand(6,9) / 10 ;
        $Dlbs = $Wlbs ;
        
    }
    
    $newWeight = $row["weight"] + $Dlbs ;

    echo "<BR> CALF CODE:" . $row["Acode"] . " WEIGHT: " . $newWeight ;
    
    echo "<hr>" ;
    
    //echo "<br>" .  $newWeight ;
    
    //$sql = "UPDATE herd SET weight = $newWeight WHERE Acode = $row['Acode']" ;
    
    }
    
}

     $>
```

Thanks for any recommendations!

Comment: Please add code here as text, not images. Images are extremely hard to read and troubleshoot

Comment: You haven't actually run the update query, you just created a query string.

Comment: Here's the code....  I left off the UPDATE because what I was trying wasn't working. Could find example that showed how to do it properly.

Comment: <?PHP  
  $Dlbs = 0 ;

 $Slbs = rand(15,19) / 10 ;
 $Wlbs = rand(6,9) / 10 ;

if ($month > 3 && $month <12) {

 $Dlbs = $Slbs ;
 
 } else {
 
 $Dlbs = $Wlbs ;
 
 }
    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM herd WHERE age <= 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  
 
 $query = "UPDATE herd SET weight = ($row["weight"] + $Dlbs) WHERE Acode = $row["Acode"]" ; 
 }
?>

Comment: It's still not formatting in readable way.  What's the secret?

Comment: You need to [edit] your post and add the code there. You cannot format code in comments.

Comment: is last closing tag $> is typomistake ?? it should be ?>

Answer (score 0):

try with single quote in update query...

```
    $newWeight = $row["weight"] + $Dlbs ;
    $acode = $row['Acode']; // check if it is Acode or acode ?
    echo "<BR> CALF CODE:" . $row["Acode"] . " WEIGHT: " . $newWeight ;

    echo  "<hr>";

    echo  "<br>".$newWeight;

    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE herd SET weight='$newWeight' WHERE Acode='$acode'" ;
    if($conn->query($sqlupdate){
         echo "updated";
        }
      }

 }

   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  Still wrestling with the looping the sqlupdate, however. While it will do a single record Update, it just doesn't want to loop through the current 6 records I want to update.  I'll keep plugging away at it. It's probably something simple that I am missing and tomorrow's another day!  :-)